# How to calculate cell height [that has long text] when printing DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview, formatting

I searched but didn't find how to set `the cell height` when printing `DataGridView` when the cell has long text.

I didn't find one result that concentrate how to calculate the height with long text. And I don't want to use 3rd party DLL file that print it with right cell height.

I use this code to calculate the height but text always cut and short text has lower cell height that on DGV.

```
var tallestHeight = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in GridRow.Cells)
{
    if (!cell.Visible) { continue; }
    var s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font);
    var tempHeight = (int)(s.Height * Math.Ceiling(s.Width / dataGridView1.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].Width));
    if (tempHeight > tallestHeight)
    {
        tallestHeight = tempHeight;
    }
    tallestHeight = (tallestHeight < 22) ? 22 : tallestHeight;
}
iCellHeight = tallestHeight;
```

I want when I print DataGridView to printer to show all the text in all cells without cutting. Long text increase the row height and if no long text row's height stays unchanged.

I have row height = 22

`Text wrap` for my DataGridView is `enabled`

Edit1:

Here is my [DataGridView properties](https://pastebin.com/eBim3NZJ)

Here is how i print my DataGridView: [PrintDGV Class](https://pastebin.com/cJiR34ZD) that i use

My DGV appears [image: DGV]

Print preview  [image: print]

Yellow highlighted text isn't complete Full text is `First Middle lastname- some text- 0130011511478- تجربةة 7427/01300/8346584584563846`

The text below it complete.

How to show the first row at full?

Comment: Why don't you use the Row Height as the measure? Do you mean that, in the UI, the text of Cells is cut off? I.e., `WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False`? If that's the case, set `AutoSizeRowMode = AllCellsExceptHeader` and `WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True` before printing, so the DGV will auto-size, giving you the correct measures, then set it back to what it was. Assuming you print the content with the same Font

Comment: @Jimi `WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True` already `True` for `DefaultCellStyle and RowsDefaultCellStyle` and i put `AutoSizeRowMode = AllCellsExceptHeader` before printing and still text still getting `cut`

Comment: @Jimi, in the UI the text of the cells is cut off, even if i set `dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders;` before printing I realize that not all cells shows full text. I have other cell with a bit shorter - but not too short text - and it shows all the text but the longer one isn't.

Comment: In the Designer, select the DGV, then in the ProperyGrid, make sure that in the DefaultCellStyle Property (which defines the style of all Cells), `WrapMode = True`. `RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` should be `NotSet` and the same for the `RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle` (note that these are more specific and override the `DefaultCellStyle`) -- You said that `AutoSizeRowMode = AllCellsExceptHeader`, so at this point, the DGV must wrap long text and size the Row as required to show it all. If it doesn't something is wrong with the setup, or it's modified in code. Check again.

Comment: @Jimi May you please check my edit1 at the question? I added my DGV properties and print class that i use and screenshots of DGV and print preview.
I don't know where the error is or if there is any modification as i checked my code and nothing change.
I get my data from `XLSX file` and add the data to `datatable` and then added it to `DataSet` and to `DataView` and it is my `DataSource` of my DGV.

Comment: Some Columns are hidden according to the user choice. If i resize some columns like the one with long text, i get all the text to appear. But not all users may resize the column(s) and they will complain that text isn't showing. I don't know why this happening.

Comment: I found that using `dataGridView1.AutoResizeRows();` will show all the text in the cell. 

If some of the text isn't visible which is usually very small part, user have to adjust the column width and it will show all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the grid settings, you need to use the output sizes to calculate the adequate height of each row to fit their contents. Also, calling a `MeasureString` method overload that takes [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?view=net-5.0) is necessary to get more accurate result.

I see in the printout image above you are dividing the `MarginBounds.Width` by the visible cells. Thus, the following:

---

#### Calculate

---

Create a method to calculate and return the proper height of each row.

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;

private int GetRowHeight(
    Graphics g, 
    DataGridViewRow row, 
    Rectangle bounds, 
    StringFormat sf, 
    int minHeight = 22)
{
    var cells = row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewTextBoxCell>()
        .Where(c => c.Visible);

    if (cells == null) return minHeight;

    var cell = cells.Aggregate((DataGridViewTextBoxCell)null, (x, y) => x != null && 
    x.FormattedValue.ToString().Length > y.FormattedValue.ToString().Length ? x : y);

    if (cell == null) return minHeight;

    var h = g.MeasureString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
        row.DataGridView.Font,
        new SizeF(bounds.Width / cells.Count(), bounds.Height),
        sf).ToSize().Height;

    return Math.Max(h + 6, minHeight); // 6 for top and bottom margins...
}
```

---

#### Call

---

Caller example and class variables to track the printing...

```cs
// +
using System.Drawing.Printing;

private int rowIndex;
private int cellCount;
private int pageNumber;
private readonly PrintDocument printDoc;
// ...

// ctor
public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDoc.PrintPage += OnPrintPage;
}

// Cleanup
private void YourForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    printDoc.Dispose();
}

// Preview
private void btnPrintPreview(object sender, EventArgs e) => Print(true);

// Print
private void btnPrint(object sender, EventArgs e) => Print();

// Print Routine
private void Print(bool preview = false)
{
    rowIndex = 0;
    cellCount = 0;
    pageNumber = 0;

    var rows = dataGridView1.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .FirstOrDefault(r => !r.IsNewRow);

    if (rows != null)
        cellCount = rows.Cells
            .OfType<DataGridViewTextBoxCell>()
            .Where(c => c.Visible)
            .Count();

    if (cellCount == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing to print...");
        return;
    }

    printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    if (preview)
    {
        using (var pd = new PrintPreviewDialog())
        {
                    
            pd.Document = printDoc;
            pd.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (var pd = new PrintDialog())
        {
            pd.Document = printDoc;
            if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                pd.Document.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Print

---

[`PrintDocument.PrintPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?view=net-5.0) event example.

```cs
// +
using System.Drawing.Text;

private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var w = e.MarginBounds.Width / cellCount;
    var x = e.MarginBounds.X;
    var y = e.MarginBounds.Y;
    int h;
    Rectangle rec;

    using (var sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        // Maybe you need to set this? I see Arabic text in the images.
        // sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;

        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

        // Uncomment to print the headers in the first page only.
        //if (pageNumber == 0)
        //{
        h = dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height;

        foreach (var col in dataGridView1.Columns
        .OfType<DataGridViewTextBoxColumn>()
        .Where(c => c.Visible))
        {
            rec = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gainsboro, rec);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(
                col.HeaderText, 
                col.DataGridView.Font, 
                Brushes.Black, 
                rec, 
                sf);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rec);

            x += w;
        }
                    
        x = e.MarginBounds.X;
        y += h;                    
        //}

        for (var i = rowIndex; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

            if (row.IsNewRow) break;

            h = GetRowHeight(e.Graphics, row, e.MarginBounds, sf);

            if (h > e.MarginBounds.Height)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insufficient height.");
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            foreach (var cell in row.Cells
                .OfType<DataGridViewTextBoxCell>()
                .Where(c => c.Visible))
            {
                rec = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

                if (rec.Bottom > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                {
                    pageNumber++;
                    rowIndex = i;
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawString(
                    cell.FormattedValue.ToString(), 
                    dataGridView1.Font, 
                    Brushes.Black, 
                    rec, 
                    sf);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rec);

                x += rec.Width;
            }

            x = e.MarginBounds.X;
            y += h;                    
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Output

---

[image: SOQ67132271]

Comment: I love the output gifs of your print method and how long text is handled. I will try it tomorrow [Here it is almost midnight] and will tell you what i get. Just quick request if you please. May you please edit it so that i can have the headers on all pages and not on the first one only? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried the code. Everything seems good except one bug. When i click print after the print preview it prints only last page. Like it doesn't see that there is other pages before it. I think because of `rowIndex` and/or `e.HasMorePages` and/or `pageNumber` variables. When i click PrintB i call `PrintPreview()` method. 

How to make it print all the pages?

Also I added `if (!cell.Visible) { continue; }` after getting row by row as it prints not visible cells.

Comment: Added this line at the constructor  `printDocument1.BeginPrint += (sender, e) => { rowIndex = 0; pageNumber = 1; };` [Made pages start at 1 instead of 0] and now it prints great. Thank you very much

Comment: @SamiJildeh Right. You need to reset the class variables whenever you start a new print job. I forget to skip the invisible cells, corrected it. Use the new revision to either print or print preview. Just call the `Print();` method to print, or `Print(true);` to preview. Good luck.