# How to print multiple pages in c#? Using datagridview

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

There are no issues or errors in the code, but I am trying to print a sales report that contains a lot of data. I only want to print what's displayed on the Datagridview because I have filters for date, month, and year. can someone please help me?

This is what I have:

```
 private void printBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }
        
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 14);
            //float fontweight = font.GetHeight();
            float pageWidth = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width;
            float pageHeight = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height;

            float currentY = 60;// declare  one variable for height measurement
            e.Graphics.DrawString("SONNY INN", font, Brushes.Black, 40, currentY);//this will print one heading/title in every page of the document
            currentY += 15;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("\r\nPhilippines\r\nContact No: 0945 678 8057\r\n\r\n\r\n", font, Brushes.Black, 40, currentY);
            currentY += 15;
            string top = "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
            graphics.DrawString(top + "\r\nLegend : RA - Room Accomodation\r\nAO - Add-Ons", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 600, 60);
            currentY += 60;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", font, Brushes.Black, 40, currentY);
            currentY += 30;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Transaction Date\tGuest\t\t\t\tRoom No.\t\tDetails\t\tAmount\t\t\tBalance Due", new Font("Courier New", 10), Brushes.Black, 50, currentY);
            currentY += 30;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 40, 750);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("TOTAL AMOUNT: PHP  \t\t\t\t\t\t" + totamtxtbox.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 50, 780);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("TOTAL BALANCE: PHP  \t\t\t\t\t" + balduetxt.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 50, 800);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("GRAND TOTAL: PHP  \t\t\t\t\t\t" + gtotaltxt.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 50, 820);


            int offsetY = 40;
            int y = 0;
            int cnt = reportgrid.Rows.Count;

        
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in reportgrid.Rows)
                {
                    string transd = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["Transaction Date"].Value);
                    string guest = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["Guest"].Value);
                    string roomno = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["Room No."].Value);
                    string deets = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["Details"].Value);
                    string amount = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["Amount"].Value);
                    string baldue = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["Balance Due"].Value);
                    graphics.DrawString(transd + "\t" + guest + "\t\t\t" + roomno + "\t\t\t" + deets + "\t\t\t" + amount + "\t\t\t" + baldue, new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 50, currentY);
                    currentY += 20;
                }

             
            MessageBox.Show("Printing in progress.", "Print Sales Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? You don't have any logic to control when the page is full. You would check y<yMax and return from the event after setting e.HasMorePages=true..

Comment: [Might Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141528/14171304).

Comment: I'm having difficulty in adding the logic @TaW

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c/27453694#27453694)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the easiest thing to print multiple pages from a DataGridView so I recommend you to use one of the existing code samples. Here's couple good ones which are easy to use and can print multiple pages:

[Another DataGridView Printer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer)

[DataGridView Print/Print Preview Solution - Part I](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36488/DataGridView-Print-Print-Preview-Solution-Part-I)

[The DataGridViewPrinter Class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13678/The-DataGridViewPrinter-Class)

Comment: Actually it is not really harder than any other things to print.